# Required Field Validation and Current Date Validation on asp textbox Control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a control like:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="_txtLeadDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <AjaxControl:CalendarExtender ID="_txtLeadDate_CalendarExtender" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="_txtLeadDate"></AjaxControl:CalendarExtender><br />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequirePreDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="_txtLeadDate" ErrorMessage="Please select a Date" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="10px" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Now I am trying to add another validation that date selected should't be a past date (only current and future date).
How can I achieve that. Kindly help.

Comment: parse date string in javascript and validate

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
           ControlToValidate="_txtLeadDate"
           ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
           Display="Static"
           ErrorMessage="Not an even number!"
           ForeColor="green"
           Font-Name="verdana" 
           Font-Size="10pt"
           runat="server"/>

<script language="javascript">
   <!--
   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
      var textbox = $('#<%=_txtLeadDate.ClientID%>');
      if(textbox.val() != ...)
      {
      }
   }
   // -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax control toolkit then try to use this code:
aspx page tag

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txt" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    runat="server">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

and write it to load event:

```
 CalendarExtender1.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

so that all previous date will become disable..

Comment: I tried using StartDate to page load. But it shows error.

Comment: use this namespace in cs page: using AjaxControlToolkit;